# LG G2 - No SIM and network also after hard reset

Tags: sim-card, lg-g2, network-signal

I have a problem with my LG G2 (D802).
It shows, without reasons, no network signal and no SIM.
I do an hard reset but nothing changed.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There could be different causes:

- The SIM card has no connection to your device. Maybe it has moved or would not be inserted correctly. It is best to remove the card and reinsert them.
- The SIM card is broken. It is best to test another sim card or to check the own card function in another device.
- The smartphone has a defect. It needs to be repaired.

There may be other sources of error and better investigation methods.

Comment: The SIM slot is clean and works well on other devices. So, is it the hardware? Is there a software to test it? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Have you tried another sim card? I don't know any software to test this. In my opinion, it is a hardware defect. But I have no LG g2, so I do not know if this problem is more frequent appearance and whether it is possibly just a software problem. If this problem occurs more often with this device, you often find answers in the appropriate forums.

Comment: Yes, I tired with another SIM and it doesn't work. Only one time the signal reappears for a couple of seconds after one of many reboots.

Comment: If it still has warranty, you should bring the device for repair.